# SharePoint 2013 - hide the Suitebar for anonymous User

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How do we hide the Suite bar for anonymous users, but always show it for admin users.

Is it not possible to do this through a snippet in the browser, on a page layout or master page, rather than cracking open SharePoint Designer?

Thanks

Comment: Does this help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822366(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: personally I've had bad experiences with SPSecurityTrimmedControl (specifically for anonymous purposes). I use an ASP LoginView instead
http://ftduarte.blogspot.se/2011/09/sharepoint-2010-easy-hide-ribbon.html

Comment: Taigo, I would  be all for that process if you can describe how that can be applied to a .html page layout or .html master template in sharepoint 2013!  If this works, than there will be no need in using designer or visual studio! awesome.

Answer (score 1):

1 – Open your site with SharePoint designer

2 – If you are using a sandbox solution go to `_catalogs/masterpage/themename`

```
If you are using a farm solution got to `_catalogs/masterpage/`
```

3 – Check out and edit in advanced mode the master page you are using

4 – Search for the comment `<!--SuiteBar start-->`

5 – Right before it paste the line below

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="ManageWeb">
```

6 – Search for

```
 <!--SuiteBar end-->
```

7 – Just below it paste the code

```
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

The SPSecurityTrimmedControl applied to remove the suite bar

Comment: Very frustrating that I cannot have full control over my visual components from one source (my .html master template).  I have to also go into Designer, to modify something displayed on same page?